# Resolving Promises sequentially not working

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a code to:

- Read last three data from Firebase
- Iterate each retrieved data
- Push a Promise-returning function expression to an array of Promise to be processed sequentially later
- Process said array sequentially

Code:

```js
firebase.database().ref('someRef').limitToLast(3).on('value', snapshot => {
  let promiseArray = [];
  
  snapshot.forEach(e => {
    promiseArray.push(() => {
      firebase.storage().ref(e.key).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        //Do something with URL
        //In this case, I print out the url to see the order of URL retrieved
        //Unfortunately, the order was incorrect
        return 'Resolved, please continue'; //Return something to resolve my Promise
      });
    });
  });
  
  let result = Promise.resolve([]);
  promiseArray.forEach(promise => {
    result = result.then(promise);
  });
});
```

I think that it should already be correct. However, the result I want to get is wrong. What did I miss?

**EDIT**

I seem to have missed a point. **In my Promise array, I want the first function to resolve the Promise it returns first before continuing to the second function.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: apparently, I forgot to my function is not returning a Promise. Because of that, when I'm chaining the `then`s, it's not waiting for my Promise to resolve first as it wasn't even returned in the first place. I'm basically returning a void, thus the functions continue without waiting for the previous Promise to resolve. Simply adding `return` fixes the problem:

```js
firebase.database().ref('someRef').limitToLast(3).on('value', snapshot => {
  let promiseArray = [];
  
  snapshot.forEach(e => {
    promiseArray.push(() => {
      return firebase.storage().ref(e.key).getDownloadURL().then(url => { //Add return here
        //Do something with URL
        //In this case, I print out the url to see the order of URL retrieved
        //Unfortunately, the order was incorrect
        return 'Resolved, please continue'; //Return something to resolve my Promise
      });
    });
  });
  
  let result = Promise.resolve([]);
  promiseArray.forEach(promise => {
    result = result.then(promise);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a synchronous method. You can use `map` to create the array of promises and then use `promise.all`.

```
firebase.database().ref('someRef').limitToLast(3).on('value', snapshot => {
  let promiseArray = [];

  const promiseArray = snapshot.map(e => firebase.storage().ref(e.key).getDownloadURL());

  Promise.all(promiseArray).then((resultArr) => {
    // Do anything with your result array
  });
}
```

For sequential execution of promises you can use `async await`.

```
firebase.database().ref('someRef').limitToLast(3).on('value', async (snapshot) => {
    let promiseArray = [];

    const promiseArray = snapshot.map(e => firebase.storage().ref(e.key).getDownloadURL());
    let result;
    for(let i = 0; i < promiseArray.length; i++) {
        result = await promiseArray[i]; 
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated my post. Won't `Promise.all(promiseArray)` run all Promises simultaneously? I want the second Promise function to wait for the first Promise function to resolve its Promise first.

Comment: Why does my code not work? I'm very sure I'm really close to getting my code to work.

Comment: You are using `forEach` which runs synchronously. So, it does not wait for any asynchronous activity in it.

Comment: I am, however, running the `promise` functions asynchronously by chaining them using `then` in my `forEach`, am I not?

Comment: It won't wait for your promises. It just sent the promise and your `then` part won't get executed, as it may return result now or later.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reduce`. A very good example you will find here: https://decembersoft.com/posts/promises-in-serial-with-array-reduce/

Comment: I've read many posts in regard to reduce. My code does the same thing, doesn't it? Why is it not working though?

Comment: Because you started all the promises in line `const promiseArray = snapshot.map(e => firebase.storage().ref(e.key).getDownloadURL());` to run simultaneously.